# Java REST on a modular app

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I already have my server with all the managers and the code to run it. It's currently using a protocol based upon TCP/IP but I want to switch to something more scalable and open like a REST api so I've tried with Jersey. The first thing that I find really boring is the lack of recent tutorials on the subject, that means that developers have to search the most recent classes by themself pausing the tutorial, the second thing that I don't get is why cannot I create a REST api like a java server, can't I open it up calling a method or something like it? Do I really need to build a webapp that loads only the class written in web.xml and "skips" the main?
Keeping it short, the question is: How can I add a RESTful API to my application without making it a WebApp?

Comment: Jersey implements JAXRS and use annotation to define your resource method.  Jersey provides you servlet implementation which scan your resource classes.  So you don't have to specific for resource classes in Web.xml,  jersey servlet finds for you!

Comment: what does it mean to "skip the main" ?

Comment: I would want to execute the normal aplication and then create a RESTful api to access it, but with all the rest apis that I found it seems to not call the main method

Comment: This is not a programming question; it seems as if you want to complain.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to write the question